# Backstack android wear not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, wear-os

I am trying to create an android wear app that only has one activity with one fragment inside of it. I want to be able to switch the fragments out based on button clicks or other user actions.

I can replace fragments just fine; however, when I swipe from left side of the screen to the right side of the screen. The app closes. I expected this swipe to act like a back button and not exit the app.

**Main activity**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentChangeListener {

    int  fragmentContainerId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);


        // instialize the fragment to the loading page
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub watchViewStub) {
                fragmentContainerId =  R.id.fragmentContainer;

                if (watchViewStub.findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) {




                    Fragment1 fragment1= new Fragment1 ();

                    // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
                    // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
                    fragment1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

                    // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container'
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment1).addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, fragment.toString()).addToBackStack(null);
        System.out.println("Entry count in backstack is: " + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment 1**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;



public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,
                container, false);

        Button button1= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment2 fragment2= new Fragment2 ();
                FragmentChangeListener fc=(FragmentChangeListener)getActivity();
                fc.replaceFragment(fragment2);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Fragment 2**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        return v;
    }


}
```

**FragmentChangeListner**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public interface FragmentChangeListener
{
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment);
}
```

When I navigate from Fragment1 to Fragment2 via the button click. How can I navigate back to Fragment1 without exiting the app?

Comment: have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to wrap your second layout inside a

`android.support.wearable.view.SwipeDismissFrameLayout`

Then you can capture the dismiss gesture and inside the parent activity call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

you can set listener on the SwipeDismissFrameLayout like so:
`swipeFrame.setDismissEnabled(true);
 swipeFrame.setOnDismissedListener(new SwipeDismissLayout.OnDismissedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(SwipeDismissLayout swipeDismissLayout) {
               getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });`

Comment: Is it possible to show the previous Fragment behind the Fragment that is being swiped away? So just like how it works with Activities.

Answer (score 0):

There's a potentially hacky solution that you can use if you consider using the [GridViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html) class instead. It allows you to swipe backwards to view previous content. You'd have to refresh the views upon swiping to simulate a dynamic backstack, but it can be done.